# Adding HTML to a page element with ajax onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax, indicator

To have an indicator while doing an ajax request, I got information saying that I should have the indicator with the animated gif placed in the page element, then on success of the ajax function replace the data.

If I add the indicator source with src="ajax-loader.html", the ajax call leaves it in place and doesn't replace it with the data.  If I add the indicator source with .load("ajax-loader.html"), before the ajax call it isn't shown at all.  If I add it in the ajax call in the beforesend event, it isn't shown either.  If I make two ajax calls, one to load the indicator, one to load the data the same happens.  There must be a way to show the indicator in this simple code.

This is the HTML for the page element.

```
   <iframe id="lcupco" style="position: relative; top: 5px; width: 100%; height: 200px; border: 2px solid grey; margin-bottom: 15px;"></iframe>
```

This is the HTML for the indicator.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'/>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code

1. Calling .load

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#lcupco').load("ajax-loader.html");});

   $.ajax({   
       url: 'luxcal/index.php?cP=40',   
       cache: false,
       async: true,
       success: function(data) {
       $('#lcupco').html(data);   
       },
   });
   ```
2. Using beforesend

`

```
   $.ajax({
            url: 'luxcal/index.php?cP=40',   
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function() { 
                $('#lcupco').load('ajax-loader.html');
                // $('#lcupco').html('<html>Initializing calendar...</html>'); //simple text didn't load either.
            },
            success: function(data) {
            $('#lcupco').html(data);   
            },
    });
```

1. Using two ajax calls: one for indicator and one for data

`

```
$.ajax({   
    url: 'ajax-loader.html',   
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
    $('#lcupco').html(data);   
    },
});


$.ajax({   
    url: 'luxcal/index.php?cP=40',   
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function() { 
        $('#lcupco').html('<html>Initializing calendar...</html>');
    },
    success: function(data) {
    $('#lcupco').html(data);   
    },
});
```

`

Comment: Umm, this is all kinds of weird.  Why are you trying to update the contents of an iframe (that doesn't seem to have an src by the way.  Also, if you want to go the iframe route, couldn't you just update the src of the iframe to get the content (no ajax necessary).  Also, could you just overlay the loader img without calling a separate page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the pre-loader gif to the index page. No need of loading it separately. Then on the load of iframe you can hide or remove it. You can see a demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/dAdtU/ . Here iframe source is set when load button is clicked. This can be done on page ready, or even you can set the source directly. When the load even gets triggered preloader is removed.

Using ajax you can load html content for replacing/modifying the inner html of a particular element in the page ( div, p, ul etc..). But using it to load the entire page is not recommended.

Comment: That's true, I could put that image on the top page.  I will look into that option as an alternative.  But since the indicator would actually show on a slide out which is not visible when the page loads.  The coding to show and hide the indicator is somewhat messy.  But if that works I might have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'luxcal/index.php?cP=40',   
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function() { 
                    $('#lcupco').append($('<img class="indic" src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/>'));
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#lcupco', '.indic').remove();
                    $('#lcupco').html(data);   
                },
        });
```

Also dont forget that the *src* attribute takes double quotes (") instead of single (')

Comment: It makes sense that I should simply append the image to the element.  But that did not fix the problem.  Could it be that the iframe doesn't like this?  I added <html></html> tags around the image, but that did not help.  Thanks for reminding me about the src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation for all the effects could simply be that you can't set the inner HTML or load the content of an iframe, because the browser determines the content of an iframe based on its `src` attribute.

Usually you wouldn't use iframe for an asynchronous call anyway, a simple div should work. With a div, setting the html before (be it with a `html()` or `load()` functions) and replacing it in complete handler will work out fine.